# Не могу понять что за nan(ind) в задаче с функциями

Tags: c++

Чтобы долго не мусолить, просто прикреплю задание, мне не нужно его решение, я просто не понимаю почему в результате мне выдает nan(ind)

```
double function(double a) {
    return (atan(1) * 4) / 2;
}

double sum(double a, double b) {
    double result = 0;
    int i = 0;
    do {
        result += sin(i * a) / i;
        i++;
    } while (abs(function(a) - result) >= b);
    return result;
}


void main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    double E = 0.001;
    double x1 = 0.05, x2 = 0.5, x3 = 3;
    cout << function(x1) << endl;
    cout << sum(x1, E) << endl;
    cout << function(x1) << endl;
    cout << sum(x2, E) << endl;
    cout << function(x1) << endl;
    cout << sum(x3, E) << endl;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У Вас в строке

```
result += sin(i * a) / i;
```

происходит деление на ноль. Начинать нужно с 1.
Ещё одна проблема связана с функцией `function`. Она игнорирует передаваемый ей аргумент. Она должна иметь вид

```
double function(double a) {
    return (atan(1) * 4 - a) / 2;
}
```

Comment: Вроде как оно теперь не ругается на это, но происходит следующая незадача, отображается только первые три cout'a, почему-то все что идет после не появляется

Comment: @ДонВлад дополнил ответ.

Comment: @ДонВлад Ещё одна маленькая ошибка: условие достижения точности вычислений |F(x) - Sum| <= e, значит в цикле условие должно быть `> b`, а не `>= b`. Ну и 10^-4 = 0.0001, а не 0.001